# Lattice points on parametric equations

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

The definition of a lattice point is a point that has integer coordinates.

Find the number of lattice points  $(x,y)$, where $-100\le x\le 100$ and $-100\le y\le 100$ are on the graph of the parametric equations \begin{align*} x&=30-40\cos t, y=-50 + 30\cos t. \end{align*}

How would I begin? There could be infinite possibilities for $t$, so I am not sure how to begin this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically ignore the cosine element - just think of it as a variable that can take any value between $-1$ and $1$ inclusive. The equations then define a line section between $(70,-80)$ and $(-10, -20)$:

$$\left .\begin{align}x&=30-40v\\ y&=-50 + 30v \end{align}\right \rbrace v\in [-1,1]$$

Then you just need to find values of $v$ in that range that make $40v$ and $30v$ both integers.

Clearly for $30v$ to be an integer, you need $v=\frac{k}{30}$, which gives 61 possibilities in range. Simultaneously you need $v=\frac{m}{40}$. This means that $30m=40k \implies 3m=4k$. Since $3$ and $4$ are co-prime, this will only happen when $3 \mid k$ and $4\mid m$, which means that the only solutions are for $v=\frac{n}{10}, n=\{-10,\ldots 10\}$

This gives a total of $21$ solutions.

Comment: Using that, how would I apply it to the equation? Does v have to be an integer? i.e. v = -1, 0, 1?

Comment: Wouldn't there be a multitude of possibilities?

Comment: @MathyPerson well certainly no more than $61 \left (\frac{\{-30..30\}}{30} \right )$. But 3 and 4 are coprime...

Comment: 59, then????????

Comment: @MathyPerson - Guessing is not the way... does $v=\frac{-30}{30}$ make $40v$ an integer? $v=\frac{-29}{30}$? $v=\frac{-28}{30}$? $v=\frac{-27}{30}=\frac{-9}{10}$?

Comment: I understand what you mean now. If v = {-30....30} / 30 is just a fraction, and not an integer, I believe that 40v would not be an integer. If this is true, then -30/30, 0/30, and 30/30 are the ones that work.

Comment: @MathyPerson well, what is $\frac{9}{10}\times 40$?

Comment: That is an integer. I will just go through and test them all, then.

Comment: Are there 21 possibilities?

Comment: @MathyPerson correct; all the options that evaluate to $\frac{k}{10}$

Comment: k/10? What do you mean? Are you referring to the 21 possibilities?

Comment: yes, from $-1=\frac{-10}{10}$ to $\frac{10}{10}=1$

Comment: Oh, ok. Is 21 the solution for the entire problem?

Comment: As far as I can see, yes. It might be nice to make a graph of the resulting points if that sort of presentation is well-received.